# Get default HDFS path that Parquet file is saved in

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

I ran a spark job that culminated in saving a Parquet file, and the job completed successfully. However, I only specified the name of the file, and did not specify the HDFS path. Is there a way to print out the default HDFS path that spark wrote the file to? I looked at `sc._conf.getAll()`, but there doesn't seem to be anything useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is one of the way (apart from simple command way is `hadoop fs -ls -R | grep -i yourfile`)....

Below is example scala code snippet.... (if you want to do it in python or java you can emulate the same api calls)
To get list of parquet files. and filter them like below....

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{BytesWritable, Text}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
//other imports here 
lazy val sparkConf = new SparkConf()    
 lazy val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)   
 lazy val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    val fileSystem = listChaildStatuses(fileSystem , new Path("yourbasepathofHDFS")) // normally hdfs://server/user like this...
  val allparquet = fileSystem.filter(_.getPath.getName.endsWith(".parquet"))
// now you can print these parquet files out of which your files will be present and you can know the base path...
```

Support methods are like below

```
/**
        * Get [[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus]] objects for all Chaild children (files) under the given base path. If the
        * given path points to a file, return a single-element collection containing [[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus]] of
        * that file.
        */
     def listChaildStatuses(fs: FileSystem, basePath: Path): Seq[FileStatus] = {
        listChaildStatuses(fs, fs.getFileStatus(basePath))
    }

 /**
    * Get [[FileStatus]] objects for all Chaild children (files) under the given base path. If the
    * given path points to a file, return a single-element collection containing [[FileStatus]] of
    * that file.
    */
  def listChaildStatuses(fs: FileSystem, baseStatus: FileStatus): Seq[FileStatus] = {
    def recurse(status: FileStatus): Seq[FileStatus] = {
      val (directories, leaves) = fs.listStatus(status.getPath).partition(_.isDirectory)
      leaves ++ directories.flatMap(f => listChaildStatuses(fs, f))
    }

    if (baseStatus.isDirectory) recurse(baseStatus) else Seq(baseStatus)
  }
```

Comment: pls check above. Hope that helps!